# How do I line break in R's networkD3 package? when using a diagonal network?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

The newline `\n` 'line break' doesn't seem to work with the networkD3 package. Or maybe I'm not applying `\n` properly. How do I line break on line #2 shown below when using the `diagonalNetwork()` function?

```
library(networkD3)
nd3 <- list(name = "Start\nSecond Line",  # line 2
            children = list(list(name = "A", 
                                 children = list(list(name = "*1"), 
                                                 list(name = "2"), 
                                                 list(name = "3"))), 
                            list(name = "B")))
diagonalNetwork(List = nd3, fontSize = 18, opacity = 0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700596/put-line-break-in-node-labels-in-networkd3-sankey-diagram

Comment: though it depends on whether you’re talking about `sankeyNetwork` or `diagonalNetwork`... pretty sure it works with Sankey but not the others

Comment: You're right. I edited my question to get rid of 'Sankey'. Got confused in my terminology. I'm curious how to do this with the `diagonalNetwork()` function.

Comment: Then the link above is relevant... the conversation there occurred before that feature was added to `sankeyNetwork`... it was never added to the other `networkD3` functions