# I used htmlwidgets::onRender to add numbers to a sankey network, but the numbers do not seem to be appear after saving the plot as png

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3, webshot

I was following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264918/r-networkd3-sankey-add-value-to-node-label) and tried using `htmlwidgets::onRender` to add numbers next to node labels. It displays the change in an html file with no problem, but then when I tried saving it as png, the numbers seem to disappear. I was using `webshot::webshot` to save the screenshot of the plot as png from the html file, and I suspect maybe this is causing the issue? Any help would be much appreciated!

*saved as html using* `networkD3::saveNetwork`:
[image]

*saved as png using* `webshot::webshot`:
[image]

code:

```
library(networkD3)

# prepare data
links <- data.frame(
  source = c("group_A","group_A", "group_B", "group_C", "group_C", "group_E"), 
  target = c("group_C","group_D", "group_E", "group_F", "group_G", "group_H"), 
  value = c(2,3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
)

nodes <- data.frame(
  name = c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) |> unique()
)

links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

# sankey network
sankey = sankeyNetwork(Links = links,
                       Nodes = nodes,
                       Source = "IDsource",
                       Target = "IDtarget",
                       Value = "value",
                       NodeID = "name",
                       fontSize = 20)

# display values
js_string <-
  '
  function(el, x){
    d3.select(el).selectAll(".node text")
      .text(d => d.name + " (n = " + d.value + ")");
  }
  '
sankey <- htmlwidgets::onRender(sankey, js_string)

# save plot
saveNetwork(sankey, "sn.html")

# save as png
webshot::webshot("sn.html", "sn.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `PhantomJS` browser that `webshot` relies on, which is not actively maintained and archived as-is years ago. See [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344). If you use `webshot2` instead, it produces your expected output. Not sure what the exact cause is, however.

```r
library(networkd3) 
library(webshot2)

# prepare data
links <- data.frame(
  source = c("group_A","group_A", "group_B", "group_C", "group_C", "group_E"), 
  target = c("group_C","group_D", "group_E", "group_F", "group_G", "group_H"), 
  value = c(2,3, 2, 3, 1, 3)
)

nodes <- data.frame(
  name = c(as.character(links$source), as.character(links$target)) |> unique()
)

links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1

# sankey network
sankey = sankeyNetwork(Links = links,
                       Nodes = nodes,
                       Source = "IDsource",
                       Target = "IDtarget",
                       Value = "value",
                       NodeID = "name",
                       fontSize = 20)

# display values
js_string <-
  '
  function(el, x){
    d3.select(el).selectAll(".node text")
      .text(d => d.name + " (n = " + d.value + ")");
  }
  '
sankey <- htmlwidgets::onRender(sankey, js_string)

# save plot
saveNetwork(sankey, "sn.html")

# save as png
webshot2::webshot("sn.html", "sn.png")
```